# Magento 2 dropdown attribute options not showing up in admin

Tags: magento2

In admin : 
Stores -> Attributes -> Product -> Color

When I add new option it is allowing to add new options. But unable to edit existing option and also not showing options in "Manage options section"

Please check attached screen shot: 
[image]

Comment: Please check data is saving on DB? Any JS Error? Try to Add New/Edit Attribute

Comment: Data is saving I can see while product add. No JS error.

Comment: have you tried to do same with other attribute?

Answer (score 4):

If you installed magento 2 through composer with the master branch instead of develop branch, the module `Magento_Swatches` is not installed/enabled. Check in your `app/etc/config.php` for a `Magento_Swatches` line.

From your CLI, do:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Swatches
```

You may need to also clear cache and deploy static content.

Visual/Text swatches should function on this screen now (and also be an option when creating a new product attribute).

Comment: Thanks! Realized we had disabled this for performance since we are using swatches as such, but didn't realize it broke this part of the admin.